# Blender particles. Grid based emitter only allows maximum of 1000 particles. Any way to increase this?

Tags: particles

I have a particle emitter attached to a cube in my scene that is emitting ico-spheres from its volume.  I want it to Emit in the grid shape (as it currently is)
[image]

except for that I want it to contain a lot more than just 1000 particles.  when I select the grid emission however, the particle amount is automatically set to 1000, and the number value in the particle settings is grayed out
(see below).
No matter what number I set it too, the particles don't change at all.

[image]

does anyone know of any way to increase this number beyond 1000 while still keeping the grid formation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resolution sets the density of the particles.

In your case you have a cube with a resolution of 10 - so 10x10x10 = 1000 particles.

For more particles simply increase the resolution.

Comment: And also get a powerful computer. The more particles, the more processing power and RAM you will need.

Comment: thanks a lot! : )